# Python os.getcwd() is not working on subfolders in VSCODE

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

I have a python file, converted from a Jupiter Notebook, and there is a subfolder called 'datasets' inside this file folder. When I'm trying to open a file that is inside that 'datasets' folder, with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
# Load the CSV data into DataFrames
super_bowls = pd.read_csv('/datasets/super_bowls.csv')
```

It says that there is no such file or folder. Then I add this line

```
os.getcwd()
```

And the output is the top-level folder of the project, and not the subfolder when is this python file. And I think maybe that's the reason why it's not working.

So, how can I open that csv file with relative paths? I don't want to use absolute path because this code is going to be used in another computers.

Why os.getcwd() is not getting the actual folder path?

Comment: What do you see when you type `pwd` on Jupyter cell?

Comment: `os.getcwd()` is working fine. The problem is in your expectations. The current working directory is the directory where Python is running, not the directory of any particular source file.

Comment: The curious thing is that in my Jupiter Notebook I have `pd.read_csv('datasets/super_bowls.csv')` and it works like a charm. But when I'm running code on a direct .py file it doesn't.

Comment: When I type pwd it gives me the Top-level folder. The structure I have is "/Users/ivanparra/AprendizajePython/jupyter/datasets". The main file is on the Jupyter folder and the csv on the datasets subfolder.

Comment: If the python file is part of a package when being run then the current working directory will be the folder where the first dunder init file is located. But if you run a module directly without it's package then that working dir will be where the python file is located.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My observation, the dot (.) notation to move to the parent directory sometimes does not work depending on the operating system. What I generally do to make it os agnostic is this:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

__location__ = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))

super_bowls = pd.read_csv(__location__ + '/datasets/super_bowls.csv')
```

This works on my windows and ubantu machine equally well. 
I am not sure if there are other and better ways to achieve this. Would like to hear back if there are.

Comment: Thank you so much. I helped me a lot! Researching more about those os modules, I get a shorter version to work.

`import pandas as pd
import os

currentPath = os.path.dirname(__file__)

super_bowls = pd. read.csv(currentPath + '/datasets/super_bowls.csv')`

Answer (score 1):

(edited)

Per your comment below, the current working directory is

`/Users/ivanparra/AprendizajePython/`

while the file is in

`/Users/ivanparra/AprendizajePython/Jupyter/datasets/super_bowls.csv`

For that reason, going to the `datasets` subfolder of the current working directory (CWD) takes you to `/Users/ivanparra/AprendizajePython/datasets` which either doesn't exist or doesn't contain the file you're looking for.

You can do one of two things:

(1)  Use an absolute path to the file, as in

`super_bowls = pd.read_csv("/Users/ivanparra/AprendizajePython/Jupyter/datasets/super_bowls.csv")`

(2) use the right relative path, as in

`super_bowls = pd.read_csv("./Jupyter/datasets/super_bowls.csv")`

There's also (3) - use `os.path.join` to contact the CWD to the relative path - it's basically the same as (2). 
(you can also use

Comment: I did that, put the dot before the slash, but it isn't working.

Comment: @IvanParra could you please add the real location of the file and the current working directory to the question?

Comment: Yes, the real location of the main file .py is `"/Users/ivanparra/AprendizajePython/Jupyter"` and inside that folder is a subfolder `/datasets/`, where is the csv file.

Comment: @IvanParra could you please print the result of os.getcwd() and post it here?

Comment: Yes. `/Users/ivanparra/AprendizajePython/`

Answer (score 1):

The answer really lies in the response by user2357112:
os.getcwd() is working fine. The problem is in your expectations. The current working directory is the directory where Python is running, not the directory of any particular source file. –  user2357112 supports Monica May 22 at 6:03

The solution is:

```
    data_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
super_bowls = pd.read_csv( os.getcwd() + '/datasets/super_bowls.csv')
```

Comment: It works, thank you. But the point of all this is that this code will be in another computers, and maybe the file structure there will be different. How can I get the relative path of the current file and not the one where python is working?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone that tried to help me. Thanks to the Roy2012 response, I got a code that works for me.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

currentPath = os.path.dirname(__file__)

# Load the CSV data into DataFrames
super_bowls = pd.read_csv(currentPath + '/datasets/super_bowls.csv')
```

The os.path.dirname gives me the path of the current file, and let me work with relative paths.

```
'/Users/ivanparra/AprendizajePython/Jupyter'
```

and with that it works like a charm!!

P.S.: As a side note, the behavior of os.getcwd() is quite different in a Jupyter Notebook than a python file. Inside the notebook, that function gives the current file path, but in a python file, gives the top folder path.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this problem a few years ago. I think it's a matter of design style. The problem is that: your workspace folder is just a folder, not a project folder. Most of the time, your relative reference is based on the current file.

VSCode actually supports the dynamic setting of cwd, but that's not the default. If your work folder is not a rigorous and professional project, I recommend you adding the following settings to `launch.json`. This is the simplest answer you need.

```
"cwd": "${fileDirname}"
```

Comment: Can you explain me what do you mean with just a folder and not a project folder? I got lost with that reference.